# JMeter every URL only once

Tags: jmeter

Pardon me if this is already answered (newbie to JMeter).
I have a situation where, I have to read 100,000 URLs from a CSV file but all the URLs should only be run once, along with achieving 500 req/sec load on server. Tried using `Once Only Controller` with a Thread count of 100, but every thread read only one URL and stops after reading first 100 URLs.

My CSV file looks like this:

    `URL1
    URL2
    ...
    URL100000`

[image]

I have called my HTTP sampler inside `Once Only Controller`
[image]

Is there something that I am doing wrong here ??

Answer (score 0):

Use the Constant throughput timer(req/min) to have your desired TPS (req/sec)
your TPS will be proportional to the number of active threads. 
Ref: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer.

Do not use Only Once Controller . It will run the thread(100 in your case) only once(each thread hits 1 URL and exits) . Rather use a HTTP Request.

Comment: That's exactly what is happening when I use Only Once Controller, how does HTTP Request solve this ? If I have 100 users (threads) all 100 users will be hitting all the URL's , which is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Throughput shaping timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/).

First in your CSV Config Make sure you set `recycle on EOF to false`, which means that if JMeter reads all lines it wont start from beginning again.

Add a throughput shaping timer to your http request and mention start RPS as 500 end RPS ass 500 and duration 200 seconds
That means you are telling JMeter to hit 100000 requests in 200 seconds (500 per second * 200 seconds=10000 requets).

To calculate thread pool size use the formula rps*Max response time/1000, Add some extra threads to this value .

For more info on throughput shaping timer please [follow this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/07/throughput-shaping-timer/)

Comment: Rohit, How does this ensure that one URL is only hit exactly once ?

Comment: By Default JMeter reads CSV file sequentially ,
So if you keep recycle on EOF to false, When JMeter reads CSV file and reaches the end of file it does not read from the beginning again.

and using throughput shaping timer you are telling JMeter to hit exact 100000 requests , so it picks unique value every time

Comment: You can use external tools to clean up the csv file before running the test, to make sure that urls are unique, such as the unix command `uniq`